# Inserting multiple values that are not "pre-known" in a single SQL statement

Tags: mysql

I want to create a stored procedure to insert multiple values into a table with values from another table. Am having a headache on creating a MYSQL statement to help achieve this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_loadIDs`()

BEGIN
declare vUserID int;

-- I know this should only return one value but dont know the work around for getting all values meeting this criterion
set vUserID = (select UserID from usertbl where DesignationID=1); 
insert into tasktbl (UserID,DefaultUser) values (vUserID,'1');

-- For known values, I know it is as easy as follows:
insert into tasktbl (UserID,DefaultUser) values ('21','1'),('22','1'),('23','1');
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do just what you want, if I've understood the requirement correctly

```
INSERT INTO tasktbl
            (UserId,
             DefaultUser)
(SELECT userid,
        '1' AS DefaultUser
 FROM   usertbl
 WHERE  DesignationID = 1);
```

Edit, following the OP's comment:

```
INSERT INTO tasktbl
            (UserId)
(SELECT userid
 FROM   usertbl
 WHERE  DesignationID = 1);
```

Comment: Wrong. The 1 is confusing us. Look at it like, set vUserID = (select UserID from usertbl where DesignationID=1); 
insert into tasktbl (UserID) values (vUserID);

Comment: Your code says `insert into tasktbl (UserID,DefaultUser) values (vUserID,'1');`. I was replicating this.

Comment: I've edited my original answer to reflect what I think you may be asking for.

Comment: Thats perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try "Insert into ... Select ... From ...", below is an example

```
INSERT INTO tasktbl (UserID,DefaultUser)
SELECT UserID, DesignationID
FROM usertbl
WHERE DesignationID = 1
```